# Using quotation marks in an R function

Tags: r, function, tidyverse

I am trying to write an R function which returns a table of summary statistics (based on the `get_summary stats`function from the `rstatix` package) and computes a Wilcoxon test. This would be performed over several *Y* variables with a constant *X* variable of interest (which would be the basis for the summary stats table).

This is how the function looks now:

```
summary_stats_and_test <- function(df, xvar, yvars){
  df_res <- df %>% 
    group_by({{ xvar }}) %>% 
    select({{ yvars }}, {{ xvar }}) %>% 
    get_summary_stats(type = "mean_sd") %>% 
    arrange(variable) %>% 
    mutate(across(where(is.numeric), ~ num(., digits = 1)))
  
  stat_test <- yvars %>% 
  paste(" ~ ", xvar) %>% 
  map(as.formula) %>% 
  map_df(~wilcox_test(.x, data = df))
  
  return(list(table = df_res, test = stat_test))
}
```

I "embraced" `xvar` and `yvars`inside the `df_res` chunk.
However, I can't seem to understand how to specify the `xvar` value inside the paste function to perform correctly.

This is some code for example:

```
weight_wc_deltas_vars = c("weight_1", "weight_2", "weight_3", "WC_1", "WC_2", "WC_3")
df %>%  
  mutate(has_weight = if_else(is.na(col_1), "no", "yes")) %>% 
  summary_stats_and_test(xvar = has_weight,
                         yvars=weight_wc_deltas_vars[1:3])
```

If `has_weight` in the function is without quotation marks, I get an error: `Error: object 'has_weight' not found`. If it's with quotation marks, I don't get an error, but the `group_by` function inside my function has no effect.

More generally, It's not so clear to me if the best practice would be to write the argument of my function with or without quotation marks in R. The concept of embracing in the context of tidyverse is clear, but here I'm stuck over the same issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code, you need to transform the name referred to by `xvar` into a string. You can do this via

```
deparse(substitute(xvar), backtick = TRUE)
```

Note the `backtick = TRUE` parameter! This is important to correctly handle non-syntactic names (e.g. `` `foo bar` ``) being passed into the function.

**But** your code also handles such names incorrectly when passed via `yvars`, and you need to fix this. One way would be to transform `yvars` into names (via `map(yvars, rlang::sym)` or `lapply(yvars, as.name)`) and then back into strings as above. But what you’re currently doing is a detour anyway. Much easier to construct the formulas directly rather than via the detour of constructing strings. That way you also don’t have to convert your `xvar` into a string.

```
  stat_test <- yvars %>%
    map(rlang::sym) %>%
    map(\(y) rlang::inject(!! y ~ !! rlang::ensym(xvar))) %>%
    map_df(~ wilcox_test(.x, data = df))
```

Comment: Thanks! Could you elaborate a bit on why you use both !! and the rlang functions in the 3rd row?

Comment: @user23485480 It’s basically explained on this page: https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/topic-defuse.html — `rlang::ensym()` defuses the parameter so that it isn’t evaluated subsequently. `!!` *interpolates* that defused variable into the expression via `rlang::expr()`. If you use only `!!`, `!!` would try to *evaluate* `xvar`, and it would fail (“object ‘foo’ not found”, if you called your function with `xvar = foo`). If you use only `rlang::ensym()`, `rlang::expr()` wouldn’t evaluate the subexpression *at all*, and you would end up with the formula `y ~ lang::ensym(xvar)`.

Comment: Hi, just to follow up on that topic, I tried the function as you suggested and get the following error: Error in `map()`:
ℹ In index: 1.
Caused by error in `x$terms %||% attr(x, "terms") %||% stop("no terms component nor attribute")`:
! no terms component nor attribute. 
I tried calling rlang::ensym on xvar before the function but it changes nothing. Not too sure what is going on TBH.

Comment: @user23485480 Yes, I made a mistake: of course `rlang::expr()` creates an unevaluated language object. We want the *evaluated* (formula) object. We could either wrap the result of `rlang::expr()` into `as.formula()` or `eval()`. Or, much better, we can use `rlang::inject()` instead of `rlang::expr()`: this function takes an expression and performs interpolation via `!!` and `{{…}}`, but otherwise evaluates the expression normally.